# mysql order by query issue

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm having some problem in using order by in mysql. I have a table called "site" with 3 fields like id,name,rank. This table consists around 1.4m records. when i apply query like,

```
select name from site limit 50000,10;
```

it returns 10 records in 7.45 seconds [checked via terminal]. But when i use order by in the above query like,

```
select name from site order by id limit 50000,10;
```

the query never seems to be complete. Since the id is set as primary key, i thought it doesn't need another indexing to speedup my query. but i don't know where is the mistake.

Any help greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the output of "explain select name from site order by id limit 50000,10"? That will help find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT name 
FROM site 
WHERE id >= ( SELECT id
              FROM site
              ORDER BY id
              LIMIT 50000, 1
            )
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 10 ;
```

Comment: Flash! thats it. You've saved my day ypercube!. Thanks for that. and this query returns 10 records after 1.45m of records in 9 secs. subperb.

Comment: 9 secs is still a very long time :)

Comment: ofcourse,but its better than what i've now. As of now this soultion seems to be optimum, but i need to get it much quicker than this and i'm working on it.

Comment: ypercube: i forgot the monitor the server load that time, may be it causes the delay. but now i'm getting the results in a second like .49secs. so this query is very useful...

Answer (score 3):

This is "to be expected" with large `LIMIT` values:

From http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/01/order-by-limit-performance-optimization/

> Beware of large LIMIT Using index to sort is efficient if you need
>   first few rows, even if some extra filtering takes place so you need
>   to scan more rows by index then requested by LIMIT. However if you’re
>   dealing with LIMIT query with large offset efficiency will suffer.
>   LIMIT 1000,10 is likely to be way slower than LIMIT 0,10. It is true
>   most users will not go further than 10 page in results, however Search
>   Engine Bots may very well do so. I’ve seen bots looking at 200+ page
>   in my projects. Also for many web sites failing to take care of this
>   provides very easy task to launch a DOS attack – request page with
>   some large number from few connections and it is enough. If you do not
>   do anything else make sure you block requests with too large page
>   numbers.
>
> For some cases, for example if results are static it may make sense to
>   precompute results so you can query them for positions. So instead of
>   query with LIMIT 1000,10 you will have WHERE position between 1000 and
>   1009 which has same efficiency for any position (as long as it is
>   indexed)

AND

> One more note about ORDER BY … LIMIT is – it provides scary explain
>   statements and may end up in slow query log as query which does not
>   use indexes

The last point is THE important point in your case - the combination of `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` with a big table (1.4m) and the "not use indexes" (even if there are indexes!) in this case makes for really slow performance...

EDIT - as per comment:

For this specific case you should use `select name from site order by id` and handle the splitting of the resultset into chunks of 50,000 each in your code!

Comment: I'm doing it for sitemap, where i've list the urls in the sitemap,generally we're not advised to have sitemap files  more than 50,000 urls or file size of 10mb . so i ordered it like site1.xml 0,50000 and site2.xml 50,0000,100000. To test this i used 50,000,10. but it is not completing the query.

Comment: I understand that but as I wrote: the combination you use disables the use of indexes... either use `ORDER BY` or `LIMIT` BUT NOT BOTH at the same in your case... see my EDIT above...

Comment: thanks for your efforts i give a try first and let you know the result.

Comment: Thanks for your lone effort, atlast i got some response from the server. As you said, I've used query like , "select name from site limit 50000,50000;" Now i'm seeing the records are listed. But some times i see record id 10 is being inserted before record id of 9 or 8. thats why i ordered when selecting. Is there any other demerits in not using order by other than what i said above?

Comment: I don't understand... use `ORDER BY` and NOT `LIMIT` and split the resultset in your code (not in the SQL) - this way the index is used and the performance is fine and the result is essentially the same...

Comment: Thanks for your efforts.ypercube given some interesting solution.